# Android 14 HealthConnectException: Conflict found, but couldn't read the entry

Tags: android, healthconnect

I am testing the health connect integration of my app on Android 14.

When I try to insert a weight, hydration or nutrition record I get the following errors:

```
Caused by: android.health.connect.HealthConnectException: android.health.connect.HealthConnectException: Conflict found, but couldn't read the entry.
    at android.health.connect.aidl.HealthConnectExceptionParcel$1.createFromParcel(HealthConnectExceptionParcel.java:33)
    at android.health.connect.aidl.HealthConnectExceptionParcel$1.createFromParcel(HealthConnectExceptionParcel.java:29)
    at android.os.Parcel.readTypedObject(Parcel.java:4055)
    at android.health.connect.aidl.IInsertRecordsResponseCallback$Stub.onTransact(IInsertRecordsResponseCallback.java:106)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1392)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1299)
```

This same code runs fine on Android 13 where the HealthConnect app is installed as a separate application and is not part of the OS.

Any help how to figure out whats the problem here would be appreciated.

**EIDT: minimal reproducible example**

```kotlin
val time = ZonedDateTime.parse("2024-03-16T00:00:00+02:00[Europe/Sofia]")

val r = WeightRecord(
    time = time.toInstant(),
    zoneOffset = time.offset,
    weight = 60.kilograms,
    metadata = Metadata(
        clientRecordId = "weight_dummy_id", clientRecordVersion = 0
    )
)

healthConnectClient.insertRecords(listOf(r)) // this throws the error
```

Before executing the code above I made sure that the following conditions are true:
`healthConnectClient.getSdkStatus(context) == HealthConnectClient.SDK_AVAILABLE`
`healthConnectClient.permissionController.getGrantedPermissions().contains("android.permission.health.WRITE_WEIGHT")`

I am using:
`androidx.health.connect:connect-client:1.1.0-alpha07`

In AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```xml
<manifest>
    ...
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.healthdata" />

        <intent>
            <action android:name="androidx.health.ACTION_SHOW_PERMISSIONS_RATIONALE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.WRITE_HYDRATION" />
    ...
    <application>
        ...
        <activity android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
            android:name=".ui.healthconnect.HealthConnectPermissionsRationaleActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.health.ACTION_SHOW_PERMISSIONS_RATIONALE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW_PERMISSION_USAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HEALTH_PERMISSIONS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT 2: package name**

I noticed that if I change the package name of the app I no longer observe this error and the record is successfully inserted in HealthConnect. My guess is that HC has some data cached for this particular package which is causing the issue.

Comment: please share a little bit of your code regarding the integration otherwise is difficult to help

Comment: @Lino added example code